# why is there no output to my program in direct x 11?

Tags: c++, directx-11

i am new to direct x 3d and know little to nothing about it. ive recently began (watching) a series of tutorials ( https://youtu.be/2NOgrpXks9A ) and cant even seem to get the 'hello world' equivalent sorted. when i run the program from the tutorial, mine does not display anything, whereas it is suppose to display an empty window. Though the problem may seem naive i don't know where else to pose a question like this...

I saw online that some people were declaring the 'winmain' arguments like:

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
   _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
   _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
   _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
   _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
```

...however, this still didn't work.
I am running on the solution platform x86 with:
-windows 10
-visual studio 2019

```
#include <Windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE  hInstance, //allows us to load bitmmaps or icons
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,//always 0
    LPSTR LPcmdLine,//contains cmd line arguments 
     int        nCmdShow)
{
    const auto pClassName = "hw3dbutts";
    //register window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbSize = sizeof( wc );
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = nullptr;
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = nullptr;
        RegisterClassEx(&wc);
        //create window instance
        HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
            0, pClassName,
            "happy Hard Window",
            WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU,
            200, 200, 640, 480,
            nullptr,nullptr,hInstance, nullptr
        );
        //show the damn window!
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
        while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

no error messages seem to occur as there is no error, however nothing is outputted and i'd like to know why...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: `while(true);`

Your minimal Win32 program needs to include a 'message pump' after you create & show the window:

```
    // Main message loop
    MSG msg = {};
    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
```

As you are new to Direct3D, I recommend you look at the Direct3D game templates on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki).

> You should take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) and it's [tutorials](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). A lot of the tutorials on the Internet are a bit dated and use the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://aka.ms/dxsdk), although they can all be useful in the right context.

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) and [Getting Started with Direct3D 11](https://walbourn.github.io/getting-started-with-direct3d-11/).

Answer (score 0):

double-check your code carefully, the problem is that you set the class name to nullptr ( wc.lpszClassName = nullptr;) and wc.cbClsExtra = 0; is repeated 2 times instead of wc.cbWndExtra = 0;